# Converting Object to an ArrayList<?> in Java

Tags: java

I am having a Map of < String, Object > . On some key the object might be a String value on some keys it might be a List. For example

```
MyMap = { "Name" : "Captain America" , "Hobbies" : ["beating people", "drawing", ".."] }
```

So, I try to access this list as,

```
List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>().addAll(MyMap.get("Hobbies");
```

But this throws an exception

```
The method addAll() in Collection() is not applicable for type {Object}
```

But as many people suggested I tried this

```
List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>((List<String>)MyMap.get("Hobbies"));
```

This too throws an error saying that it cannot be converted. How to do this. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: That design doesn't look very robust. How about creating a SuperHero class with name and list of hobbies and put SuperHero objects in a list?

Comment: No this is just a template of how my map looks like. Is this not possible to convert to List of strings from Object ?

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to throw different types of object in the same list.

Comment: It is possible but it is bad design.

Comment: @Srikanth Please use better examples, unless you want us to think this is what you're doing. BTW, what are you doing that needs such odd conversions?

Comment: @ModusTollens I will consider changing my design thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @NomadMaker I will consider having a class. But the scenario is like I can have a String as one data member which is permanent but the other may be a single string data member or a List of Strings. That is what I was trying to convey

Comment: @Srikanth It depends on the actual problem, but in that case you'd normally have a list with several strings or a list with one string. It's still better to use a proper class though.

Comment: @Srikanth I would seriously consider rethinking that idea. If it is absolutely necessary, then always have a list of strings, with sometimes the length being one.

Comment: @NomadMaker I have changed the description can you look at it once more and tell me if its ok. This is the actual scenario I am facing

Comment: @Srikanth The correct answer is: don't do it like this. Do it by creating a class (see kemerisandrius answer).

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't change your question in a way that would invalidate an already posted answer. I'm going to roll it back.

Comment: @ModusTollens If I follow a class design what will be the type of the second data member because it is not always String or List<String>. It can be String or List<Integer> or also something else. So I assume in that case also we should use Object right?

Comment: @Srikanth No, you should avoid using Object whenever possible. Create classes tailored to the problem instead. There should almost never be a reason to use Object.

Comment: How about having two List's. One of them holds the items with just a String, and the other with the one's with a List?

Answer (score 2):

You could at least have a list of one item instead of having String. So it would look like:

```java
MyMap = { "Name" : ["Captain America"] , "Hobbies" : ["beating people", "drawing", ".."] }
```

However this seems like it should be a class instead of a map. It could look something like:

```java
public class SuperHero {
   private String name;
   private List<String> hobbies;

   ...
}
```